# Ember.js: Binding property in template in an app with routing

Tags: binding, routes, ember.js

I am developing an Ember app and it is really great. But I have a annoying problem I can not solve. I use routing in my app and two diffent controllers with their own views. If I try to use a binding property from the first controller to the second one, that property is not reflected in the second view. In a short way I have something like this:

```
router = Em.Router.extend({.....});
App = Em.Application.create({
    Router: router,
    FirstCtrl: Em.Controller.extend({x:'ABC'}),
    FirstView: Em.View.extend({...}),   
    SecondCtrl: Em.Controller.extend({xBinding:'Em.App.router.firstCtrl.x', y:'123'}),
    SecondView: Em.View.extend({...}),
});
App.initialize();
Em.App = App;
```

If in the template for the second view I have something like this:

```
Binding property: {{x}}
Property with no binding: {{y}}
```

'ABC' is not shown in the view but there is no such problem with '123'.

In my browser I can access that property from Javascript console with Em.App.router.firstCtrl.x but Em.App.router.secondCtrl.x returns undefined.
So, my question is Why can't I access that property? How should I write that binding?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Em` at the beginning of binding is required, Try this..

```
SecondCtrl: Em.Controller.extend({xBinding:'App.router.firstCtrl.x', y:'123'}),
```

Well summing up the comments:

All the `controllers` defined in ember must end with **Controller** while routing, for example if you call `router.get('applicationController').connectOutlets('home')` its corresponding controller shall be `App.HomeController` or `App.homeController`

while binding use `'App.router.yourController.yourProperty'` instead of `'Em.App.router.yourController.yourProperty'`

We can also use `connectControllers` in order access properties across controllers if you want to avoid global bindings

Comment: I already tried it but doesn't work. Above that, a warning message "WARNING: Watching an undefined global, Ember expects watched globals to be setup by the time the run loop is flushed, check for typos" appears continuously

Comment: Is it the Router(must start with capital R) being router(lowercase) ??

Comment: I only use Router (capital R) when creating App (Em.Application.create({Router: ....}). When accessing that property I always use Em.App.router (lowercase). Isn't it the right way? I've tried both ways with no success

Comment: We should always use the defined property, As you defined Router(starting with capitals in your App, the first property defined) you should use the same...I think it should work probably there should be other reason for this issue, can you build up a fiddle ?

Comment: From http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html "The Router instance will be available as the router property of the application". Nevertheless, it doesn't work. Trying to reproduce it in [link]http://jsfiddle.net/erbihanka/Y32ta/ but any property rendered so far

Comment: Finally solved my issue. First of all, controllers in Router should be ended in Controller (It was rigth in my code but wrong in the above example). But the most important thing as you said is that I had to declare SecondController: Em.Controller.extend({xBinding:'App.router.firstController.x'}). Having in the binding 'Em.App....' doesn't work. Here is an updated fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Y32ta where you can also see how to access controllers/views with camelcase names (as in my real code)

Comment: Is there a reason for the line `Em.App = App;`? I don't think you want to be modifying the `Em` namespace in general, unless you're modifying ember.js itself.

Comment: @erbihanka A nicer way to do this that avoids global bindings, is to use `connectControllers`. Here is a fork of your fiddle that demonstrates it. http://jsfiddle.net/JJq3E/2/ You'll notice that I also refactored it into what IMHO is easier to follow and better ember style.

Comment: @LukeMelia What is the difference between connectControllers & Bindings ?

Comment: @pauldechov There is no reason for `Em.App = App;` I deleted it from my fiddle. I think that I started my app based in an example where it was so. In their comment they said _Add the application's namespace to Ember so we can access it from within handlebars templates_

Comment: @LukeMelia I did not know `connectControllers` method. I've been reading doc about Ember.Controller and looking at your fiddle and your right, it's a better ember style. Thank you.

Comment: @Unspecified binding a controller to another on a global path means that the controller knows about the specific global property path of another object in the system. Using `connectControllers` means that the controller simply expects a local property to be defined somehow. In a test that may be a mock object; in your app, it will be a the actual controller. Generally speaking, it is a good idea in object-oriented programming to reduce coupling between objects, and to avoid dependencies on globals.